# How do i know which default settings are enabled for Sun JVM?

Tags: java, jvm, jvm-hotspot

i want to try CompressedOops on my JVM. No I wonder if it might be enabled by default. I run this jvm on debian/squeeze:

```
$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_22"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_22-b04)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.1-b03, mixed mode)
```

Some people say it is enabled by default, some say it is not:

from: http://forums.yourkit.com/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3185

> Yes, you are right, I also checked it
>   and Compressed Oops is not activated
>   by default in Java6u21 64-bit, I do
>   not understand why it said so in the
>   links I provided.

I tried to check it with jconsole/JMX but had no luck to find an attribute named CompressedOops or alike.

Does anybody know where i get a list of all jvm options for a specific build with their default values?

regards
Janning

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1880299/what-gc-parameters-is-a-jvm-running-with

Comment: I'm 90% sure it's *not* enabled by default. Not that you should let that convince you :)

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You can run with `-XX:+PrintFlagsFinal` to print the values of all flags at startup of the JVM.

Alternatively, you can use the `jinfo` tool to check the value of a flag in a running JVM:

```
> jinfo -flag UseCompressedOops 7364
-XX:+UseCompressedOops
```

Use `jps` to find the pid of the process.

Comment: This is a great answer. But for me it doesn't work as expected on debian squeeze: Unable to open socket file: target process not responding or HotSpot VM not loaded. it shows me a long list of values if i call it just with 'jinfo <pid>' but in this view i don't see if CompressOops is set.

Comment: `jinfo` can also be used to turn on/off the flag dynamically, e.g.  `jinfo -flag +HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError <pid>` if the flag is manageable. jinfo is very useful -- even if little known -- tool.

Comment: The options really useful: `-XX:+PrintFlagsFinal`