# What are the default Java GC parameters

Tags: java, java-8, garbage-collection

I'm using OpenJdk 1.8 Java and need to set some GC parameters.

I can't find any docs specific to openJdk that tell me if it supports the same GC parameters as Oracle's version, but I am assuming it does.

When I refer to Oracle docs (such as [this one](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gctuning/sizing.html#heap_parameters)) it gives default settings for Solaris-64. I am using Linux so I'm unclear what the defaults are on that O/S. I've checked the command help (i.e. java -X) and it doesn't even list the potential parameters let alone their defaults.

So my question is, where is this all documented? I'm happy with Oracle docs rather than OpenJdk, anything is better than nothing!

Comment: In practice, these defaults are rarely depending on the operating system. The actual selected GC algorithm is more important. But if in doubt, just run `java` with `-XX:+PrintFlagsFinal`.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1880299

Comment: For the record.  1) The default GC parameters are not comprehensively documented anywhere (to my knowledge).  Or at least, not officially.  ([This page](http://stas-blogspot.blogspot.com/2011/07/most-complete-list-of-xx-options-for.html) still exists, but it is 10 years out of date.)  2) There is no distinct OpenJDK documentation.  But it is not needed because Oracle and OpenJDK are built from the same codebase, and behave the same way.

Comment: "need to set some GC parameters", can you elaborate why you think so? it surely looks like you want to do this out of a need, but we do not know it.